# Uploading image with Intercom API

Tags: node.js, intercom, intercom.js

I am trying to send an image to Intercom using the user reply API. [User Reply API doc](https://developers.intercom.com/reference#replying-to-a-conversation)

There is an option to provide the image urls as attachments to the user reply, but is there a method to upload an image from the file system directly as an attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the Intercom API does only support attaching file URLs, rather than the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the image URL link within the `attachment_urls` section for sending.

```json
{
  "message_type": "comment",
  "type": "admin",
  "body": "Docs",
  "admin_id": "6956236",
  "attachment_urls": [
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1409704770/photo/close-up-lavender-flowers-in-beautiful-field-at-sunset.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=AMncBX6r3gLl3MgfobtBI013noVbZk7JAUparGJFCME="
  ]
}
```